# ngf - file upload only allow images

Tags: angularjs

I use ngf for file uploads and I havn't found a directive only to allow images to upload.
Does anyone have any hint houw to do this?

```
<button type="submit" ngf-select="vm.uplo..." ngf-multiple="false" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="5MB">Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `ngf-pattern`. To allow: `.jpg` To Not allow: `!.jpg`. Remember always to validate server side as well.

```
   ngf-pattern="'.pdf,.jpg,video/*,!.jog'" // comma separated wildcard to filter file names and types allowed
```

To answer your comment @Juraj Kojdjak:

`ngf-pattern` allows you to put custom patterns and you could for example exclude a img ext type, `ngf-accept` is a straight forward way of accepting * images.

I have used file upload but not these directives

Comment: what is the difference between ngf-pattern and ngf-accept?

Comment: ngf-accept is based on accept HTML attribute, ngf-pattern is used to customise what you want in your input